# Publish or manage permissions are not permitted to be requested with read permissions

Tags: ios, facebook, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I get the error

```
[ERROR] :      message = "Publish or manage permissions are not permitted to be requested with read permissions.";
```

when I click on my apps' login with facebook. my colleague how ever does not. same code, same modules etc.

```
Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.5.0.201602170821
(c) Copyright 2012-2014 by Appcelerator, Inc.  All rights reserved.
Build: jenkins-appcelerator-rcp-master-340 (origin/master)
Date: 17 February 2016, 08:22:10
```

Version info

```
# ti --version
5.0.6
# appc --version
5.2.0
```

Help please. I am trying to build iOS 9.2 on appcelerator.

thanks

Answer (score 8):

The message is correct. Facebook does not allow you to request both read and write permissions at the same time anymore.

At login, request read permissions and then later (it's suggested the first time you need it) request write permissions.

More information and the required methods can be found in the Facebook Module API reference by Appcelerator:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook